# TensorFlow Inception without Slim

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any version of the Inception model for ImageNet training coded without TensorFlow's Slim? I would like to make adjustments to the code but I'm not familiar with Slim...

Thank you!

Comment: Not that I am aware of. However you will find that slim is just a shorthand for full tensorflow. If you wanted to you could port it over to normal tensorflow by copy the functions each line refers to and filling in the variables. You'll find that there is a lot of copy and paste and that a lot of it is very similar so it might not be too bad. In theory you will find that this gives you much more flexibility but I am not sure how this will affect the full retraining code and application of weights.

Comment: Thanks @JCooke, I ended up "transcribing" the code myself.